# Put DateField Icon to Left on its TextInput field

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, datefield

Regarding the dateField, there is the TextInput and the Icon. I want the icon to appear on the left side of the TextInput instead of it appearing on the right side as it is in the default state.

Can somebody give me a hint about this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DateField is still a Halo component, you need to extend it to be able to change its children.  You'll want to create a new component, extend DateField and then override the createChildren and updateDisplayList functions.  Check how the DateField creates it's children and change their location accordingly.  The updateDisplayList function is for when the component resizes so you can resize the children properly.

Comment: I have no experience with custom components..Can you help me with some pieces of codes and guide me through creation of the DateField that I require.

Thanks

Comment: So, you're essentially asking me to do it for you?  I gave you the details you needed, now go research and learn.  I'm not here to hold your hand, I'm here to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Overridding the updateDisplayList did the task. i Have the following in the method:

downArrowButton.move(x,y);

However at the moment I am hardcoding the x and y values. Will try to use the height and width of the component and do some mathematical calculation and show the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://sherifabdou.com/2008/03/autosuggest-flex/) (see source code). There is an autosuggest component, but the principle is the same. Or this should be enough:

```
public class myDateField extends DateField
{
    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
        this.textInput.x=this.getChildAt(1).width;
        this.getChildAt(1).x = 0;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did - same solution described by J_A_X, but with code, cuz I think the way Adobe is setting position is a little confusing if you're new to ActionScript.  I like ChRapO's approach, but I chose to try to be consistent with the way the MX DateField component sets position of these elements.

My extended DateField class:

```
package com.escalationpoint.tagger.view.component
{
import mx.controls.DateField;
import mx.core.mx_internal;

use namespace mx_internal;


public class DateField extends mx.controls.DateField
{
    public function DateField()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        // Unfortunate that we can't call super.super.updateDisplayList
        // since we're redoing work done in super.updateDisplayList.  Oh, well...
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        var w:Number = unscaledWidth;
        var h:Number = unscaledHeight;

        var arrowWidth:Number = downArrowButton.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth();
        var arrowHeight:Number = downArrowButton.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight();

        textInput.setActualSize(w - arrowWidth - 2, h);
        textInput.move(arrowWidth + 4, 0);

        downArrowButton.setActualSize(arrowWidth, arrowHeight);
        downArrowButton.move(0, Math.round((h - arrowHeight) / 2));
    }
    }
}
```

Compare to the updateDisplayList method in the original DateField component:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                              unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    var w:Number = unscaledWidth;
    var h:Number = unscaledHeight;

    var arrowWidth:Number = downArrowButton.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth();
    var arrowHeight:Number = downArrowButton.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight();

    downArrowButton.setActualSize(arrowWidth, arrowHeight);
    downArrowButton.move(w - arrowWidth, Math.round((h - arrowHeight) / 2));

    textInput.setActualSize(w - arrowWidth - 2, h);
}
```